# Jonas 5.2.4 not launching from terminal

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, jvm-arguments, jonas

I am currently trying to deploy a web app on Jonas 5.2.4 (using the "full" version of the server), on a W7 Entreprise. All environment variables are setup accordingly. The problem being the following : in Eclipse JUNO (4.2), with the Jonas Support Plugin(5.1.2), the server launches, but fails deploying (apparently a known compatibility problem between maven and said plugin), so I went and tried to do it in console, but even launching jonas with `jonas start` basicly returns this : a popup window showing

```
`Windows cannot find '-Djava.awt.headless=true'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again`
```

and showing following message on the console

```
The system cannot find the path specified.

OW2 JOnAS 5.2.4 [ http://jonas.ow2.org / jonas@ow2.org ]

JONAS_BASE is set to C:\dev_tools\jonas-full-5.2.4
The system cannot find the file -Djava.awt.headless=true.
'-Djava.awt.headless' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know the -Djava.awt.headless is an argument passed to the JVM, and I don't know why Windows considers it as a path to a file.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem, or can provide a solution ?

Edit : A clean reinstall worked after 4 times (I have no clue why), but I'd still like to know what happened since the only file I had done anything to was the jonas.properties, only to change the services to be loaded when Jonas started.

Comment: Because your startup script is missing the command itself `java`

Comment: I actually checked that first (since I did not change any of the Jonas  .bat scripts, and it was indeed in the script), and I did not find any actual way to resolve the problem.
A full clean of anything related to Jonas and a reinstall for the 10th time finally got me out of that pitch, and Jonas started properly, but I still don't know what happened before.